# why the old view is still on the screen after hot load in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

As I mentioned in the title, the old view is still on the screen after I update the code and hot load.
Need help.
[image]

Comment: what if you run your code again?

Comment: Please show some code to pin point error..

Comment: run `flutter clean` at the terminal and `pub get`, re-run the program,

Comment: use hot restart some times hot load cannot update view instead use hot restart

Comment: It doesn't work if I hot load or run again, I have to stop it and run again, then it refreshes. I am wondering if it has something to do with the stateful widget, the home widget of the main func is a stateful widget

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports in all your dart files, I was facing the same issue, somehow one of the imports is defined from root directory that restricts hot reload as well as hot restart.